# Loading css according to dev or prod environment

Tags: symfony, webpack

Config :
Symfony 3.4 - Webpack Encore

in practice, I need to use a different background-color on body, according to the dev, test or prod environment.

I know I can do something like this in twig :

```
{{ app.environment }}
```

But I'm not sure it's a good practice !

Is there a way to do that through my yaml configs (config_dev.yml, config_test.yml, config_prod.yml) ?

Or a way to do that through my webpack.config.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using current environment as a body CSS class has nothing wrong in my opinion. I.e.

```
<body class="{{ app.environment }}">
```

and then you don't even have to load different CSS stylesheets, you only need different classes definitions in the same CSS, e.g.

```
body.prod {background-color: white}
body.dev {background-color: lightyellow}
body.test {background-color: lightgreen}
...
```

Comment: It looks like my first idea, but without any "if". So it's better. thank you

Comment: Whoops, sorry for the inital typo and thank you for editing it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that on the documentation of Webpack: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html#defining-multiple-webpack-configurations

Is it what you're looking for ? To change stylesheets depending on your environment ? All you have to do is to configure wich stylesheets you want for your different environments and launch the webpack compilator with the correct config.

Comment: it looks good But if I do it, I have to add parameters in terminal build command (--config-name). I am not sure to want this (it means one command for each environment.. it's too much to remember and source to possible errors.